# My business visit visa got refused and I need some help

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

Recently I got a job after doing some freelance and voluntary work, but the new job required me to travel to UK for 6 weeks. So I had to apply Business visit visa myself and they provided me invitation letter and Employment letter for that. I did a mistake stating my living costs wrong as I was thinking future living cost with my new job, but they took it as past/current costs. And I provided my one month bank statement as address proof but they took it as financial statement instead. They said, I failed to show sufficiently strong family, social, professional or economic ties to satisfy me. They refused me under V4.2(a)-(e) of Appendix V:Immigration Rules for Visitor. I really worried as I will lose this job without visa, so I need some help. Anyone here could you guide on applying this back and providing necessary documents I should for this to be accepted. Like I said my previous exp is voluntary/unpaid worked in visa form and I want to show my income source as Family/Friends currently and future is my salary I'm getting from the company I'm joining shortly.

Thanks